# Round table, two distinguished people

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There is a collection of $2n(n \ge 2)$ people and we distinguished two people. We assume that all individuals randomly sit at a round table. Let $A$ be the event that highlighted two person sat next to each other and let $B$ be the event that highlighted two person sat opposite each other. Then what is the relation between $P(A)$ and $P(B)$

Intuitively I think that $P(B)>P(A)$, but I'm curious how looks the solution to this problem.

Comment: Did you try the $n=2$ case? You'll get some hints.

Comment: Let everyone around the table sit down one by one at random seats, and further let the two distinguished people be the _first_ two among these to sit down. Does that help? What seats can the second distinguished person choose from?

Comment: if $n=2$ then considering $P(A)$ event they can seat for $2*2!$ and  considering $P(B)$ we have $4*2!$ possibilities, am I right?

Comment: so in general $P(A)=n*2!$ and $P(B)=2n*2!$ is this ok?

Comment: sorry should be the opposite I confuse the P(A) with P(B)

Answer (score 1):

Label the people $a, b$, and label the seats $1,2,....,2n$ (going clockwise round the table). Suppose Person $a$ is sitting in seat $i$. They are opposite person $b$ if and only if person $b$ is sitting in seat $i+n \mod 2n)$. Cycling through $1 \leq i \leq 2n$ gives $2n$ possible ways of this occurring. $$ $$ Now assume $A$ is sitting next to $b$. If $a$ is in seat $i$, then $b$ may be either in eat $i-1$ **or** $i+1$, and both these cases are different. Cycling through $1 \leq i \leq 2n$ again gives $4n$ possibilities in this case. So $P(A)=2P(B)$. $\square$